# Prove to be or be proved to be?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a hard time telling those phrases apart. "Something/someone proves to be" and "something/someone be proved to be"

> 1- After 10 years in jail he ***was proved to be*** innocent.
>
> 2- After 10 years in jail he ***proved to be*** innocent.
>
> 3- After the biopsy result her nodule ***has been proved to be*** harmless.
>
> 4- After the biopsy result her nodule ***has proved to be*** harmless.

Comment: Avoid the issue and drop *to be* altogether—which isn't needed anyway. Simply say *was proved innocent* or *was proved harmless*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little or no difference in meaning, and only a subtle difference in nuance.

Both "was proved" and "has been proved" are in the *passive* tense, which implies the result of action by some (possibly unstated) subject.  For example:

> active: The psychic claimed the latest reports **proved** her predictions to be correct.
>   passive: The psychic claimed her predictions **were proved** correct (by the latest reports).

So a sentence like, "... he *was proved* to be innocent," implies that *someone* did the proving.

"Proved", by itself, implies a condition or result.  While in most cases we can assume some kind of evidence or human action, the nuance is simply, "this is how it is" or "this is what happened".

As used in your examples:

> He **proved** to be innocent (= "the *end result* (of some unstated process) was that he was innocent")
>
> Her biopsy **proved** to be harmless (= "the test *reached the conclusion* that the cancerous growth was harmless")

Again, both have more or less the same meaning.  Whether something *was proved* true, or *proved* true, the underlying intent is to claim that it *is* true.

Related note:  There is some debate/confusion about whether to use *proved* or *proven*.  I think both are acceptable past participles of *prove*, and which you choose is pure personal preference.